# Iniciar dos procesos y esperar que el segundo proceso termine para terminar el primero

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estimados usuarios de la comunidad luego de iniciar dos procesos de forma simultánea, como puedo hacer para que en Python 3 espere a que el segundo proceso se termine de ejecutar y luego termine el primero, he intentado con time.sleep()
Pero ello solo me da un tiempo determinado, la idea es que el código sea capaz de determinar cuando el segundo proceso está completo para terminar el primero
Ej.: si ejecuto Word y luego Paint, que este cierre Word una vez que Paint (como segundo proceso) esté abierto
De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: `import os`

`import time`


`def programa():
    os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files\rutaPrograma\PrimerPrograma.exe")`

`    os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\bin\pycharm64.exe"),time.sleep(10)`

`    os.system("taskkill /f /im PrimerPrograma.exe")
    quit()`

`programa()`

eso seria un ejemplo de lo que intento hacer.
no se ve como codigo en la respuesta. no entiendo muy bien por que

Comment: Añade el código de este comentario en la pregunta, después selecciónalo y márcalo como código (botón `{}` de la barra de herramientas) para que se vea correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de cómo lances los subprocesos.

Por los ejemplos que das (Word y Paint), asumo que trabajas en Windows. Existen diferentes formas de lanzar subprocesos desde python, pero no todas ellas te permiten comunicarte con el subproceso lanzado para tareas tales como esperar a que termine, obtener su estado de salida o forzar la terminación del mismo.

La forma más flexible es [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

El ejemplo siguiente abre dos aplicaciones (Notepad y Paint), tras lo que se queda esperando a que Paint termine y cuando esto ocurre, fuerza la finalización de Notepad.

```
from subprocess import Popen

notepad = Popen("notepad")
paint = Popen("mspaint")

paint.wait()
notepad.kill()
```

Investiga el manual de Popen si quieres pasarles argumentos a los programas o 
enviarles señales u obtener su código de estado de salida.

Comment: lo intento de esa forma, pero no cierra notepad cuando abre Paint.
La idea es que cuando se abra el segundo programa que sería Paint en este caso. Cierre automáticamente notepad

Comment: No, claro, el notepad lo cierra cuando Paint termina, no cuando paint se abre. Si relees la pregunta, verás que esto es lo que preguntabas. Se abren ambos programas a la vez, se espera a que el segundo (Paint) termine, y entonces se termina el primero. Tras este último comentario ya no entiendo lo que quieres hacer, ya que: 1) primero abrimos notepad, 2) ¿Esperamos a qué? 3) Entonces abrimos Paint y cerramos notepad

Comment: Creo que lo mencione, anteriormente cuando digo, " si ejecuto Word y luego Paint, que este cierre Word una vez que Paint (como segundo proceso) esté abierto"
1º abrimos notepad y Word
2º esperamos a que Word este abierto y cerramos notepad 

la idea es, por ejemplo:
 os.startfile(PrimerPrograma)
 os.startfile(SegundoPrograma)

para que cuando el segundo programa se abra, este envié orden y cierre el primer programa

Por lo pronto Agradecer por la disposición y el tiempo de ayudar

Comment: @FrancoM Ah, creo que entiendo.... Lo que ocurre es que estás confundiendo el concepto de proceso con el de ventana. El proceso se crea instantánamente cuando llamas a `Popen()` o a `startfile()`, pero ese proceso recién creado aún tardará un rato (décimas de segundo, tal vez) en crear la interfaz de usuario y mostrar su ventana. Entiendo entonces que te refieres a este segundo evento, es decir, cuando esa ventana esté visible, entonces cerrar el programa anterior.

Comment: Exacto! :D

Estaria Muy Agradecido de que pudieras ayudarme en eso! :)

Comment: @FrancoM Tal vez deberías formular una pregunta nueva, del estilo de "¿Cómo se puede saber desde python si una ventana Windows está visible?" o similar...

Comment: ese es el punto. es complicado formular la pregunta de forma correcta.